# Tensorflow equivalent to numpy.diff

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a tensorflow equivalent to [numpy.diff](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)?

> Calculate the n-th discrete difference along given axis.

For my project I only need n=1

Comment: Numpy has such a function because it can be used for numerical calculations, as TensorFlow is symbolic, it can compute the real gradients symbolically, as well as evaluate them. Then why do you need an equivalent?

Comment: To calculate a mask over my sequence input, which would eventually (elementwise) multiply the loss. I could do it outside TF and feed it in, but it would be more cumbersome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
def tf_diff_axis_0(a):
    return a[1:]-a[:-1]

def tf_diff_axis_1(a):
    return a[:,1:]-a[:,:-1]
```

To check:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x0=np.arange(5)+np.zeros((5,5))
sess = tf.Session()
np.diff(x0, axis=0) == sess.run(tf_diff_axis_0(tf.constant(x0)))
np.diff(x0, axis=1) == sess.run(tf_diff_axis_1(tf.constant(x0)))
```

Comment: Embarrassingly (for me) straight-forward. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I don't think TensorFlow has an equivalent to numpy.diff, so you'll have to implement it, which shouldn't difficult as [numpy.diff](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.12.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1709-L1768) simply slices and subtractes:

```
def diff(a, n=1, axis=-1):
    '''(as implemented in NumPy v1.12.0)'''
    if n == 0:
        return a
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError(
            "order must be non-negative but got " + repr(n))
    a = asanyarray(a)
    nd = len(a.shape)
    slice1 = [slice(None)]*nd
    slice2 = [slice(None)]*nd
    slice1[axis] = slice(1, None)
    slice2[axis] = slice(None, -1)
    slice1 = tuple(slice1)
    slice2 = tuple(slice2)
    if n > 1:
        return diff(a[slice1]-a[slice2], n-1, axis=axis)
    else:
        return a[slice1]-a[slice2]
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting in Tensorflow 2.4, you may use [`tf.experimental.numpy.diff`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/experimental/numpy/diff).

Note that there are unsupported arguments: `prepend` and `append`.