# Tensorflow. No Loop way of subtract consecutive entry in tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

So for each 1D array `x = [1,3,4,7,8,9,2,5]`. I'm looking for an output that is `[2,1,3,1,1,-7,3]` results from `x[i] - x[i-1]`

Similarly, for a 2D tensor.

```
[[1,3,14,4,2],
 [7,5,1,5,8],
 [9,2,1,5,7]]
```

The results would be

```
[[2,11,-10,-2],
 [-2,-4,4,3],
 [-7,-1,4,2]]
```

Comment: Check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609618/tensorflow-equivalent-to-numpy-diff

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow equivalent to numpy.diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609618/tensorflow-equivalent-to-numpy-diff)